# cloudfront to apache on EC2 .htaccess redirect not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-cloudfront

I have Apache Virtual Server on EC2 directly connected to cloudfront distribution.

**http to https and www to non-www redirect not working with the following `.htaccess`**

````
```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```
````

**Requests to http://example.com return 200 OK**

**Response Headers:**

````
```
HTTP/2 200 OK
content-type: text/html
content-length: 53335
date: Tue, 06 Jun 2023 07:28:02 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2
last-modified: Thu, 08 Dec 2022 10:14:20 GMT
etag: "d057-5ef4e4ce33700"
accept-ranges: bytes
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
via: 1.1 259df3f3acee8ca070d87aedc7b2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: MXP63-P1
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
x-amz-cf-id: oxvbXrSwIpgwMjr9_5ucSj0x9YF3qRL4ablFSQqlgT==
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```
````

and here the **Request Headers**

````
```    
GET / HTTP/2
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-GPC: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
TE: trailers
```
````

**That is the Cloudfront configuration + Route 53 Configuration :**

[image: Cloudfront configuration + Route 53 Configuration]

Comment: "and it returns errors" - What are the errors?

Comment: HI, i edited the Question with images and better formatting so that it is more clear. Please take a look at the new information supplied

Answer (score 0):

You've instructed CloudFront to only access your origin over HTTP (the **Protocol** setting under **Origin domain**), and you are not forwarding your viewer Host header to the origin (the **CachingDisabled** cache policy). That means your viewer requests will look differently than you expect on your origin:

```
http://example.com -> http://ec2.*.compute-1.amazonaws.com
https://example.com -> http://ec2.*.compute-1.amazonaws.com
http://www.example.com -> http://ec2.*.compute-1.amazonaws.com
https://www.example.com -> http://ec2.*.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

You can accomplish this by making two changes in CloudFront:

1. Change **Viewer protocol policy** to **Redirect HTTP to HTTPs**
2. Add a CloudFront Function that redirects www to the apex [1]

For the first option, you can also set the origin protocol to **Match Viewer** so that your origin request will match what the viewer sees—and your htaccess rule will kick in. But this will be less performant than letting CloudFront do it at the edge, closer to your viewers, because a redirect request will now have the added latency of traveling to your origin each time.

[1] Take a look at `index.js` in this example for the structural pieces to implement this - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/redirect-based-on-country